# HTML5 two or more imports

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to import 2 files with HTML5 import.

```
  <link rel="import" href="/pages/templates/menuAdmin.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/pages/templates/header.html">
```

But I don't know how to get the second one. I have one js file but I don't know what to do next

```
var doc= document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
console.log(doc);
var text = doc.querySelector('template');
var clone = document.importNode(text.content, true);
document.querySelector('.sidebar-menu').appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use querySelectorAll instead

```
var doc= document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]').import;
```

Then use it as array

```
doc[0]
doc[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all `imports`, you have to use `querySelectorAll` and iterates on the items.

```
var docs = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]').import;

for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    doc = docs[i];
    console.log(doc);
    var text = doc.querySelector('template');
    var clone = document.importNode(text.content, true);
    document.querySelector('.sidebar-menu').appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think about it. I can't up vote. Sorry :(

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation. Now I have. Thank you again :)